# I am stack at this AI clone project console showing me this message The `value` prop is required for the `<Context.Provider>`

Tags: reactjs, runtime-error

`    import { createContext } from "react";
import runChat from "../Config/gemini.js";

```
export const Context = createContext();

const ContextProvider = (props) => {
const onSent = async (prompt) => {
await runChat(prompt);
 };

 onSent("What is react js");

 const contextValue = {};

 return (
  <Context.Provider value={contextValue}>{props.children}</Context.Provider>
  );
  };

 export default ContextProvider;


  i've checked every component where i am using <Context.Provider>`
```